# can't bind to own dependency property

Tags: .net, silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

I have a Downloader, which has a progress property, which is:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Progress", typeof(int), typeof(Downloader), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnProgressChange)));

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(ProgressProperty); }
        private set { this.SetValue(ProgressProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnProgressChange(DependencyObject @object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Downloader d = @object as Downloader;
        if (d.PropertyChanged != null) d.PropertyChanged(d, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
    }
```

When I try to consume it in other class xaml (m_downloader is a private field of Downloader type):

```
<sdk:Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,12,0,0" Name="ProgressLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Content="{Binding Path=m_downloader.Progress, StringFormat='\{0\} %'}" />
```

nothing happens. During debug I can see that d.PropertyChanged is always null. How make it work to display progress in label?

**EDIT 1:**

m_downloader works like this (after temporary change to property):

```
public partial class AudioPlayer : UserControl
{
    public AudioPlayer()
    {
        m_downloader = new Downloader();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
    public Downloader m_downloader {get; private set;}
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've done the binding in Blend, it changed the xaml to this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="audioPlayer" x:Class="Media.Controls.AudioPlayer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="125" d:DesignWidth="410" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    ...
    <sdk:Label Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,12,0,0" Name="ProgressLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" Content="{Binding m_downloader.Progress, ElementName=audioPlayer, Mode=OneWay}" />
    ...
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Why the ElementName is set to the name of **nesting**, instead of the nested one? It doesn't make sense to me... But it's working after this change.

Comment: if m_downloader is private you can't bind to it. It needs to be public.

Comment: I changed to public, but still no luck...

Comment: Are you sure, that DataContext is set right, so you can bind to m_downloader?

Comment: I'm not setting DataContext... Where should I do it?

Comment: So where EXACLTY is m_downloader located? Post code.

Comment: Silverlight can bind from one dependency property to another without either class needing to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, as it seems your `Downloader` class does.  Silverlight won't subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of your `Downloader` because it wired the binding up to the dependency property's change notifications instead.  That should explain why `d.PropertyChanged` is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are after an explanation, the binding mechanism works likes this:

1. The binding mechanism depends on two things: the Path and the Source on the Binding
2. The Path in your case, is the "m_Downloader.Progress", and if the source isn't set explicitly, the binding falls back to using the DataContext on the label
3. If there isn't a DataContext set on the label, it searches for a DataContext 
   up the visual tree.
4. You can set the source explicitly using {Binding Source=...} or {Binding ElementName=...}

For example, the following will not work:

```
<sdk:Label 
   x:Name="ProgressLabel"
   Content="{Binding Path=Progress}" />
```

This is because there is no source, and DataContext isn't set.

You can set this in code using:

```
ProgressLabel.DataContext = m_Downloader
```

Alternately, you might wish to bind relative to the nesting object.

```
<sdk:Label
   Content="{Binding m_Downloader.Progress}" />
```

However, this will not work as

1. m_Downloader isn't public, and
2. m_Downloader isn't even a property
3. DataContext isn't set.

To resolve this, use the following:

public Downloader Downloader {get; set;|

public void InitializeComponent()
  {
     // ...

```
 // set DataContext to nesting object
 ProgressLabel.DataContext = this;
```

}

If you don't want to set DataContext in code, you can set the source explicitly. Since AudioPlayer has an Element Name

```
<UserControl x:Name="AudioPlayer" ... />
```

You can reference it in your binding

```
<sdk:Label
   Content="{Binding m_Downloader.Progress, ElementName=AudioPlayer}" />
```

Finally, you can also do this by setting the DataContext on the AudioPlayer to itself.

```
<UserControl
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

<sdk:Label
   Content="{Binding m_Downloader.Progress}" />
```